# Iterating over all sequences of 3 letters in a string (Python)

Tags: python

I need to create a function that iterates over all sequences of 3 letters (3-mers) in a message. For example, if message = "THE CAT", it should return "THE", "HE ", "E C"," CA", "CAT".

I've tried this code below, but it doesn't give me **every** permutation:

```
for i,j,k in zip(message[0::3], message[1::3], message[2::3]):
    return i,j,k
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that a `return` inside a `for` loop will only happen once (the first time you get to it: it returns from the function, and no more loop).

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
[message[i:i+3] for i in range(len(message)-2)]
```

(edit: -2)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much.